# How to get all possible values from a key in localstorage?

Tags: local-storage

When I go to a website in Chrome and go to the application, then local storage, I get a table for that website, a line would look something like "Key: Test | Value: yes"

So as you can see, there is a key and a value, is there any possible way to see all possible values for a key? Basically all other possible options besides "yes" in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

The entries in localStorage are up to the web developer to define. Thus, the valid values each entry can contain will depend on the application. A developer with some experience could take guesses on what those values might mean, but he would have to analyze the specific application first.

Answer (score 0):

For general case,

```
for ( var i = 0, cnt = localStorage.length; i < cnt; ++i ) {
      console.log( "Key:" + localStorage.key(i) + "  Value: " + localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key(i) ) );
    }
```